# GMap.NET.GMapControl with custom map provider?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, gmap.net

I want to use another map provider in my GMapControl.

For example, I can use GoogleMap:

```
GMapControl myMapControl = new GMapControl();
myMapControl.MapProvider = GMapProviders.GoogleMap;
```

All build-in map providers are stored in [GMapProviders](http://www.nudoq.org/#!/Packages/GMap.NET.Presentation/GMap.NET.Core/GMapProviders).

How can I add my custom [GMapProvider](http://www.nudoq.org/#!/Packages/GMap.NET.Presentation/GMap.NET.Core/GMapProvider)?

I need to add [2Gis](http://api.2gis.ru/doc/maps/quickstart/) map provider.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a WMSProvider class in:

[WMSProvider](https://github.com/ArduPilot/MissionPlanner/blob/master/ExtLibs/Maps/WMSProvider.cs)

It works fine, by changing szWmsLayer and CustomWMSURL vars.

Comment: Yeahh,. I posted only to help other users with the same question

Answer (score 3):

you need to trace tile urls using fiddler, then copy existing map provider class and modify urlformat, unless this provider use some esoteric projection, thats it, otherwise you need to know the projection details and make a custom projection class, check the source at https://greatmaps.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest or github.

Comment: Thanks. Can I find some guideline for this? Or some example?